# BLE iBeacon support in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing **Windows Phone 8.1** app based on **LE iBeacon**,

I want to discover nearby **LE iBeacon** devices from my Windows Phone 8.1 without
pairing.

When I turn Bluetooth on in my windows phone, I can see device's Bluetooth name.
But I can't do anymore.

It stands for only **Advertising or Broadcasting**. Its supported in **iOS and Android**.

Is iBeacons supported or limitation in WP 8.1? Can we exchange data to iBeacons?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, as of now Windows Phone 8.1 can only operate on devices already paired by using the Phone's Bluetooth interface.

So, there's no way to use BLE devices not already paired...

Comment: But I think its not support iBeacon technology. @Ravenheart